# Why does Google Chrome lower YouTube volume when I receive a Google Chat notification?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, youtube

When I'm listening to a YouTube video in one tab, and in another tab I get a "Clink" notification that somebody sent me a message in Google Chat, the YouTube volume drastically decreases for about 10 seconds and then fades back in...

This is really annoying when I'm listening to music.. Or anything at all on YouTube.

I have no idea what's causing this.

It could be YouTube/Chat itself (they're both Google...)

It could be Google Chrome

It could be Windows 10 recognizing that 2 processes have competing sound?

What can I do to disable this "feature"

It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I was barking up the wrong trees...

It's Windows 10.

http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-7-automatically-reduces-system-volume-for-games-pc-calls/

Edit --

Link says Windows 7, but this is the same fix for 10.

Go to the Control Panel -> Sound -> Communications -> Do Nothing

[image: Sound -> Communications -> Do Nothing]

Comment: Can you include the information from that link so when it dies your answer will still be useful? Also you say that the issue is Windows 10 but the article is for Windows 7?

Comment: Information included... The advice for Win 7 works great in Win 10, too